# Fields not populating on page load but are populating on action event

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a method that populates input fields:

```
 private void populateMostRecentStory(string selectedUser)
    {
        recentPK = getRecentStoryPK(selectedUser);
        if (Int32.Parse(recentPK) != -1)
        {
            string[] returnedValues = retrieveLastStory(recentPK);
            if (returnedValues[0] != null)
            {
                int i = 0;
                int x = 0;
                foreach (var item in catagoryDropDown.Items)
                {
                    if (item.ToString().Equals(returnedValues[0].ToString()))
                    {
                        catagoryDropDown.SelectedIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                foreach (var item in applicationDropDown.Items)
                {
                    if (item.ToString().Equals(returnedValues[2].ToString()))
                    {
                        applicationDropDown.SelectedIndex = x;
                        break;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
                dateInput.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(returnedValues[1]);
                incidentInput.Text = returnedValues[3];
                hoursInput.Text = returnedValues[5];
                descriptionInput.Text = returnedValues[6];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            clearStoryData();
        }
        dataBindFields();
    }

    private void dataBindFields()
    {
        catagoryDropDown.DataBind();
        dateInput.DataBind();
        applicationDropDown.DataBind();
        incidentInput.DataBind();
        hoursInput.DataBind();
        descriptionInput.DataBind();
    }
```

It works great when the action event for changing a drop down menu occurs:

```
//user drop down
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    populateMostRecentStory(userNameDropDown.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

But on page load, all of the fields populate correctly except catagoryDropDown and applicationDropDown:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populateMostRecentStory(getPKofUserLoggedIn());
    //Assign SQL parameter to user drop down list so that the list shows the logged in user first   followed by other users in alphabetical order
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["userLoggedIn"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

I had to use a different method to get the primary key because userNameDropDown.SelectedItem.Value results in a NullExceptionError at page load. I have tried to DataBind it beforehand and it doesn't work.

Regardless, if I print out the value of getPKofUserLoggedIn() on page load its: 45 and when I print out the value of userNameDropDown.SelectedItem.Value when select it and the action event fires it is also 45.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what you're binding the drop-down lists to but from first glances, you're trying to enumerate it before you're bound it.

Comment: Wow, I spent too much time on a silly mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that `catagoryDropDown` and `applicationDropDown` are empty at Page_Load. 
You need to bind them, or somehow fill them in some `Init()` method which will be called before `Page_Load` (or simply fill them on `Page_Load` before calling `populateMostRecentStory`)